Firebase Cloud Messaging - use as an SDK developer
I am developing an SDK, not an app, and I want to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) and Firestore into it. From what I understand, the google-services.json file includes the package name. Since I am creating an SDK, I can't specify a package name. Is there a way to use FCM without having to create a separate project in the Firebase Console for each app, allowing the SDK to be used across multiple apps?

FCM isn't designed for use as a general SDK.  It requires per-application configurations to work correctly.  The host app will need an app configuration in Firebase in order to use FCM as documented. The app configuration is required so that FCM can locate a specific app on a specific device for message delivery.  FCM can not possibly target a specific SDK in any app on any device where it's installed.
